# scratchbox arm cannot execute c compiled program

Tags: mono, arm, qemu, scratchbox, cross-compiling

Hi i set up a scratchbox with a arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc toolchain and qemu emulator.

When i want to run inside scratchbox [sbox-arm:/]> a ./configure script (from a mono tarball) i am getting the error:
`checking whether the c compiler works... ...

configure error: cannot run c compiled programs.

if you meant to cross compile, use --host.`

When i compile a simple hello.c it works but
when i execute hello.o i am getting an error:
`lib/ld-linux.so.3 no such file.`

(edit:
by using a toolchain with uClibc the error is:
`/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0` )

i can workaraound this error by using the -static flag, but that won´t work with the .configure problem.

has anyone a solution for this?

edit2:
Seems like i fixed it by setting up scratchbox again from zero, some compiling works now without static linking.